# Correct way to update wp_script() url/src?

Tags: php, scripts, wp-register-script, customization

I tried to update the url/src of the queued `$wp_scripts` correctly... my aim is to use just relative paths. Therefore I:

1. loaded the `$wp_scripts`
2. replace the domain and
3. saved the output.

But it seems that is not the correct way to updated this variable. Pls explain me way.

```php
/*
 * Correct all script urls for multiple (alias) domain issue
 */
function update_scripts_urls() {
    global $wp_scripts;

    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
        $src = $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
        $link = parse_url(home_url());
        $domain = $link['scheme'].'://'.$link['host'];
        $src = str_replace($domain, '', $src); // replace domain
        $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src = $src;
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'update_scripts_urls', 101);
```

### EDIT

It seems like `$wp_scrips` gets updated but the in the header output it shows still the full script url (eg. `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://domain.local/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>`)? Does the update happens in the to late?

Comment: [`script_loader_src`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_src/) filter is the proper way to do this.

Comment: Thx works like charm!